# How to separate string using by commas in multicomma line

Tags: java, stringtokenizer

What should I do to for separate (test(1,2) , test(3,4)) as test(1,2) and test(3,4). What can I use as delimiter value instead of x here? Thanks

```
    StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(str, "x");
```

Comment: don't use code like this. StringTokenizer has been deprecated for several versions of Java. Use the new options/functionalities of Java

Comment: User `String.split()` instead. You can provide a regexp there to do the job. Also, is it a simplified example? Can you have more than two arguments for a `test`? Nested tests? If that is, you probably want to use a parser instead.

Comment: @Pavel Smirnov i will wont have more than 2 arguments. Will be test(4,5) , test2(6,7) , test3( 78,63) test4(.....

Comment: Please have a look at: https://www.baeldung.com/java-split-string
If anything is still unclear then, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
    String s = "(test(1,2) , test(3,4))";
    s=s.substring(1).substring(0,s.length()-2);
    String[] arr = s.split(" ,");
    System.out.println(arr[0].trim());
    System.out.println(arr[1].trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.split()` instead:

```java
String s = "test(1,2), test2(4,5), test3(2,3)";
String[] arr = s.split("(?<=\\w*[(]\\d,\\d[)]),");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

Output:

```
[test(1,2),  test2(4,5),  test3(2,3)]
```